# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined but keeps giving as error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am trying to get the cart content by using {cartItem.length === 0 ?()}
from my code below

```
 <Col md={8}>
     <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
      {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
        <Message variant='info'>
          Your cart is empty <Link to='/'>Go Back</Link>
         </Message>
            ) : (
           <ListGroup variant='flush'>
               {cartItems.map(item => (
           <ListGroup.Item key={item.product}>
               <Row>
                  <Col md={2}>
                 <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                  <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                 </Col>
```

Comment: How have you defined cartItems? Perhaps you could show us the whole component.

Answer (score 0):

instead of checking length is 0 try to put condition checking if cartItems.length > 0, this will solve the issue as the length coming is undefined since you are equating it with zero gives you error.

Answer (score 0):

try to use
if its not working then share your complete file.

```
{cartItems&&cartItems.length>0?(your success case):(<Message variant='info'>
      Your cart is empty <Link to='/'>Go Back</Link>
     </Message>)}
```